# How to fetch previous row value from database?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose, I have the below table, let it be table "A".

```
Select * FROM A;
  ID       Score
  1        25
  2        36
  3        12
  4        14
```

I want to query that selects score in ascending order and also prev score value(stored in newly created column "prev_score") like the one shown below.

```
  ID       Score      Prev_Score
  3        12            0
  4        14            12
  1        25            14
  2        36            25
```

Can this be done using a single sql query?

Comment: yes, it can be done.

Comment: Is Prev_Score within the same table or elsewhere.. You haven't given us much to go off of.

Comment: i don't know a direct solution. but, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Assuming no ties... Select x.*, max(y.score) prev from a x left join a y on y.score < x.score group by x.id order by x.score

Comment: @Option, Table A has only 2 fields, id and score. I need to order the score value and also display the previous score in a temporary column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a *correlated subquery* that gets the *previous* value:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Score, 
       COALESCE((SELECT Score
                 FROM mytable AS t2
                 WHERE t2.Score < t1.Score
                 ORDER BY t2.Score LIMIT 1), 0) AS Previous
FROM mytable AS t1
ORDER BY t1.Score DESC;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/TKTNC8297)

**Edit:**

If you want score in ascending order then just switch the `ASC` / `DESC` keyword:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Score, 
       COALESCE((SELECT Score
                 FROM mytable AS t2
                 WHERE t2.Score > t1.Score
                 ORDER BY t2.Score DESC LIMIT 1), 0) AS Previous
FROM mytable AS t1
ORDER BY t1.Score;
```

Comment: thank you very much. However, I want score in ascending order. I tried removing DESC. It orders ascending score but fetches next score

Comment: @DeekshithBanjan Then you should edit the OP to reflect this requirement. Just switch the ASC/DESC keyword.

Comment: sorry but I tried it that way by switching it to ASC. The problem is, it shows next value instead of previous one.

Comment: Ok, I have found it. Thank you once again @Giorgos

Comment: It must be "t2.score <  t1.score" in the second query